# Core Data: How to get first row in grouped data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios7

So I've read about how to use Group By in core data, but it seems to be restricted to return only the grouped property and values returned by aggregate functions.

Specifically I want the data of the first row in each group by.

My app has conversations between the app user and other people. On the front page it will only show the last message in each conversation.

My thinking was that like in MySQL, I could just group by peer and order by date (desc). But in core data it doesn't let me fetch properties that are not aggregated.

Should I break it up into one Conversation entity which has many messages. And store the fields I want in the conversation entity (so I don't have to do nested lookups)? Or is there a way to accomplish this with just the one 'Message' entity?

The exception I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named 
in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions 
((<NSAttributeDescription: 0xd271240>), name oid, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good case study for the problem of "database think" standing in the way of a really simple object graph solution.

In your list of users, you are probably using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. The entity you fetch is the user, let's call this `NSManagedObject` subclass `User`.

In the `User` class, you just need to implement a method to fetch the last message. (You could also implement this in the list, but logically it belongs to the entity.) E.g.:

```
-(Message*)lastMessageToUser:(User*)user {
   NSSet *filteredMessages = [self.messages filteredSetUsingPredicate:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"receiver = %@", user]];
   NSArray *sortedMessages = [filteredMessages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
     @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:"receivedDate" ascending:NO]]];
   return sortedMessages.count ? sortedMessages.firstObject : nil;
}
```

In your list you now simply call this method on the user in your table view row to get the message.

*Additional advice: Implement this in a category of the `User` class, so it does not get overwritten if you have to re-generate your model classes in case the model changes.*

Comment: This is similar to what I had in mind with creating an additional 'Conversation' entity. However I am worried that performance will be bad if I first fetch all conversations, then for each I grab the first message. (In your example it would fetch all messages for every user, but it could of course be simplified with a fetch request with a limit of one message)...

Comment: With the above (including filter) you do not have to worry about performance.